# ogr2ogr DXF to PostgreSQL some LINESTRING coordinates mirrored to the negative longitude

Tags: gdal, postgresql, export, ogr2ogr, dxf

I have been using **ogr2ogr GDAL tool** to migrate geospatial data from DXF file to PotgresQL database without much problems. But now there is a special problem I can not fix.

I have a **DXF file with LINESTRINGs** that when I import them **to the PostgreSQL database** some of the linestrings are imported in the correct geometric coordinates but **some other LINESTRINGs are imported with the negative longitude**, so that LINESTRINGs are mirrored to the west.

When I open the DXF file with my QUANTUM GIS viewer I can see all the LINESTRINGs together with the correct coordinates, but when I export them to the postgres database and I print them in a map (by a web application) or later I export then I see some of the LINESTRINGs mirrored "away home" from the original coordinates.

That is my ogr2ogr commandline:

```
ogr2ogr -select "" -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=192.168.*.* user=**** password=**** dbname=****" C:\PATH\FILE.dxf -s_srs "EPSG:23031" -a_srs "EPSG:23031" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -nlt LINESTRING
```

There is no error output from the ogr2ogr tool, so it is difficult to get the reason of that problematic.

Any help or recommendation?

I have tried without much effect the ogr2ogr opions: -lco GEOM_TYPE=geometry -lco DIM=2 --config PG_USE_COPY YES -lco PRECISION=YES -clipsrc xmin ymin xmax ymax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I can't find the origin of this problem** but I finally reached the final objective through another tool, with the **GIS**:

1) open the DXF file with QGIS

2) convert the DXF to Shapefile (right click on the layer > "Save as...")

3) use the Shapefiles to PostgreSQL converter in the menu option: Database > Split > "Import Shapefiles to PostgreSQL"

Trough this tool I imported the DXF to PostgreSQL without the wrong coordinates problem. I suppose that in the DXF to Shapefiles conversion the origin of the problem is solved.

If anyone have more information about what can origin that situation when I use the ogr2ogr tool it would be nice to know, because right know **I cannot make that conversion (DXF to PostgreSQL) automatic** (with an script that would execute the ogr2ogr command).